# "consumers choosing to rely" vs. "consumers to choose to rely"

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitive-vs-gerund

> Signals that are related imperfectly to actual quality will mislead those consumers **choosing/to choose** to rely upon these inaccurate signals.

In the provided context, is **choosing** and **to choose** interchangeable?
Or do they provide a different meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complicated sentence:

> Signals that are related imperfectly to actual quality will mislead those consumers choosing/to choose to rely upon these inaccurate signals.

Let's simplify:

> Some signals will mislead people (choosing/to choose) to rely upon them.

These two choices have *very different* meanings.

The first one, "choosing", means:

> 1) Some signals will mislead **people choosing** to rely upon them.
>
> 1) Some signals will mislead **the people who are choosing** to rely upon them.
>
> 1) Some signals will mislead **people who trust them**.
>
> 1) Some signals will mislead **people who [had already] decided to trust them**.

The second one, "to choose", means:

> 2) Some signals will mislead people **to choose** to rely upon them.
>
> 2) Some signals will trick people, and **cause people to choose them**.
>
> 2) Some signals will trick people **into** choosing them.

So:

The first one (choosing) says that the people **already decided** to trust them.  We don't know why they chose to trust the signals.

The second one (to choose) says that the people **decided after the signals misled them** to trust the signals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) It is really helpful. Does "Some signals will mislead people who choose to rely upon them" also have the same meaning as the first one,**choosing** ?

Comment: And if I were to need to write something meaning the 2nd, I would instead write "Signals that are related imperfectly to actual quality will mislead those consumers *into choosing* to rely upon these inaccurate signals."

Comment: @MartinThompson agree!  I had that example in my draft but cut it for simplicity.  I’ll put it back. :-)

Comment: @jammyyang Yes, also the same as #1.

Answer (score 3):

They are both correct in your sentence but don't have the exact same meaning, so it depend what you mean by "interchangeable".